# What is a differentiable distribution on a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, definition

Assume $M$ is a smooth manifold and $d:u\to Q_u<T_uM$ is a distribution on $M$.

What does "$d$ is a differentiable distribution" mean? What does it mean for $Q_u$ to depend smoothly on $u$?

Comment: I imagine there are more natural ways, but if you introduce an auxiliary Riemannian metric, then for any distribution there is a type (1,1) tensor field  $P$ that describes the orthogonal projection of $P_u: T_uM \to Q_u$. The distribution should be differentiable if and only if this tensor field is differentiable.

Comment: Thank you, @JHance. How may we describe the tensor field $P$?

Answer (score 4):

As you wrote a distribution is a choice of a subspace $Q_u$ in each tangent space $T_uM$ such that $\dim Q_u$ is constant, say $k$. The distribution is smooth if around each point $u_0$ there are $k$ smooth vector fields $X_1,\cdots,X_k$ such that $Q_u = \rm span(X_1(u),\cdots,X_k(u)) \rm $ .
Namely, the distribution is locally generated by a smooth basis.